# how can display play and pause button in videoplay on flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

how can display play and pause button in videoplay on flutter? And when user click the play, how do hide the button?

I used this methods, but it was only show very small icon... how can to do like facebook play & pause button?

```
InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _controller.value.isPlaying
                                        ? _controller.pause()
                                        : _controller.play();
                                  });
                                },
                                child: Stack(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    AspectRatio(
                                      aspectRatio:
                                          _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                                      child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                                    ),
                                    Icon(
                                      _controller.value.isPlaying
                                          ? Icons.pause
                                          : Icons.play_arrow,
                                      size: 26,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
```

Comment: Set icon size ?

Comment: @Kahou I wish can change icon image, like faceook play icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tried it

```
Stack(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    AspectRatio(
                                      aspectRatio:
                                          _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                                      child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                                    ),
                                    Center(
                                      child: _controller.value.isPlaying == true
                                          ? Visibility(
                                              visible: false,
                                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                                radius: 30,
                                                backgroundColor: Colors.white60,
                                                child: Icon(
                                                    _controller.value
                                                                .isPlaying ==
                                                            true
                                                        ? Icons.pause
                                                        : Icons.play_arrow,
                                                    size: 26,
                                                    color: Colors.blue),
                                              ),
                                            )
                                          : Visibility(
                                              visible: true,
                                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                                radius: 30,
                                                backgroundColor: Colors.white60,
                                                child: Icon(
                                                    _controller.value
                                                                .isPlaying ==
                                                            true
                                                        ? Icons.pause
                                                        : Icons.play_arrow,
                                                    size: 26,
                                                    color: Colors.blue),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
```